# jQuery tabs prevent scroll to anchor

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jQuery tabs like ths...

```
   <div id="tabs">
       <ul class="tabs-menu">
           <li><a href="#tab1" class="selected">Tab 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tab1">
            Tab1 Content
        </div>
        <div id="tab2">
             Tab2 Content
        </div>
   </div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

This works correctly but when I try and open the URl with tab2 active with **www.example.com/page#tab2** then the page scrolls to the anchor point instead of loading from the top.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Show your jquery code for tab call ?

Comment: Have updated op now with the jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabsselect` listener .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();  // This will kill the default behavior.
            window.location.href = ui.tab;
        });
});
```

Comment: `evt.preventDefault();` may do what you want. See update.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></script>


<div id="tabs" style="margin-top: 2%;min-height: 500px;">
      <ul style="background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, #286090, #3b8a69); ">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Menu privilege</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Transaction Rule</a></li>

      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
        <h1>
        Tab1</h1>

      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
        <h1>
        Tab 2</h1>
      </div>
      </div>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#tabs').tabs();
});
```